# Why was this question on control systems for quadcopters closed?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, closed-questions

I do **not** understand why the following question was closed. Please note that I am **not** its author.

- [If the Quadcopter is a MIMO Nonlinear System, How Can it be Controlled using PID?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/49616/15311)

Allegedly, this question is off-topic.  How so?

In my humble opinion, two good reasons to close this question are:

1. It does **not** provide any mathematical model of any quadcopter and, thus, one cannot design controllers for it.
2. It does **not** provide any references, though it should be easy to find references on control systems for quadcopters.